# How to reset Mac user password while having working TouchID access

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, password

Do to the some reason I have not figured out yet, after having changed my MBP password (via the boot screen password expiration overlay triggered by [jamf](https://www.jamf.com)) I can't seem to authenticate with either the old or the new password, yet I can still use my TouchID to login.

How can I reset my password given that I am still able to authenticate with TouchID?

I assumed that getting a root shell would allow me to reset the password with `passwd` but can't get past `sudo -i` without a valid password.

Since I can authorise with TouchID I tried opening the root terminal with applescript:

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/open -a iTerm .  & > /dev/null 2>&1 &  " with administrator privileges
```

The script triggers the ootb GUI authentication dialog which I can approve with TouchID, and it shows the iterm2 terminal window in root mode, but the window is not interactive, i.e. it does not accept any keystrokes.

Is there any possible solution out of this other than backing up everything while I still have access to files, and then reinstall the OS from scratch? (FileVault is enabled.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Proceed at your own risk*

You can try to add TouchId as a method to authenticate `sudo`.

In Finder go `/etc/pam.d/`, copy `sudo` to your desktop.
Edit this file in a text editor and add `auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so` as top line. It should look like:

```
# sudo: auth account password session
auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so
auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_permit.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_permit.so
```

Now copy this `sudo` file to `/etc/pam.d/`. Finder will ask you if you want to replace the existing file. If you select `replace`, Finder will ask you to authorise the action via TouchID.

From that point on you can invoke `sudo` with TouchID.

Comment: Accepting the answer because I wanted to get a root terminal which I managed to do using the Finder method as you suggested. The password change via `passwd` was successful but the new password wouldn't be accepted by the system. Since I had iCloud FileVault recovery enabled I went that route instead.